# How to open a port on a Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance, I want port 3000 to be accessible to the outside world. Here's what I have done so far.

[image: firewall rule screenshot]

I have configured that at the VPC network/Firewall Rules section. But still.

[image: tcp3000-denied]

Comment: Are you trying to test a node app? Use `curl` and not `telnet`. Also make sure that your node.js app is running on `0.0.0.0:3000` and not `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 1):

Having the firewall rule open does not necessarily means a service will be listening on the other side.

Make sure you verify what ports are being listened on your Windows Server by following the tutorial in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows).

Then you should also verify the Windows firewall for blocking these ports.